# How to read file line by line and put it into oracle db

Tags: database, oracle

This is my file which I want to read:

```
20140901|2X-PRG-CZ|PRG|2X|2X-PRG-CZ|||TYPEX||QXTXGXS|QS|QS-PRG-GW|PRG|TYPEB|Y|2|98|0|0
20140901|2X-PRG-CZ|PRG|2X|2X-PRG-CZ|||TYPEX||QXTXGXS|OK|OK-PRG-MQ|PRG|TYPEB|Y|14|672|0|0
20140901|2X-PRG-CZ|PRG|2X|2X-PRG-CZ|||TYPEX||QXTXGXS|EK|EK-PRG-KK|PRG|TYPEB|Y|1|48|0|0
20140901|XS-SIN-OL|MAD|3V|3V-MAD-OO|||STXOL||QXTXGXS|7X|7X-BRU-EP|BRU|TYPEB|Y|1|59|0|0
20140901|XS-SIN-OL|MAD|3V|3V-MAD-OO|||STXOL||QXTXGXS|3V|3V-LGG-SP|LGG|TYPEB|Y|1|193|0|0
20140901|XS-SIN-OL|MAD|3V|3V-MAD-OO|||STXOL||QXTXGXS|7X|7X-PAR-EP|PAR|TYPEB|Y|1|59|0|0
20140901|XS-SIN-OL|MAD|3V|3V-MAD-OO|||STXOL||QXTXGXS|YA|YA-MAD-GS|MAD|TYPEB|Y|4|923|0|0
```

My standalone program is like this..

```
package com.dbConn;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class DbConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int updateQuery = 0;

    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        System.out.println("Connecting to the database...");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@124.18.10.22:1521:INT9", "nitin",
                "nitin");

        String filePath = "D:/ishan1/R3AP201409_GMSTYXCODG_00740_20140902024214.SND";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        System.out.println("inputStream :" + inputStream.toString());

        String name = "Hamilton";
        String email = "fred@abc.com";
        String str = inputStream.toString();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO  EXT_SITATEXT_ONLINE_ERROR(SERVICE_ID, USAGE_DATA, FILE_NAME_LINE_NUMBER)values (?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection
                .prepareStatement(sql);

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(filePath))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

        statement.setString(1, name);
        statement.setString(2, str);
        statement.setString(3, email);

        statement.executeUpdate();
        updateQuery = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        if (updateQuery != 0) {
            System.out.println("table is created successfully and "
                    + updateQuery + " row is inserted.");
        }

        int row = statement.executeUpdate(filePath);
        if (row > 0) {
            System.out.println("A contact was inserted.");
        }
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e);
    }
}}
```

In this code I want to read line by line the file from my drive and insert the line by line into the oracle db.

Comment: You are storing audio as String?

Comment: Why are you creating your own loading program instead of using SQL*Loader or an external table?

Answer (score 0):

i think snd is a binary format, if you intent to play it later - you should store the entire snd contents in a blob/securefile or something like that

Comment: I need to read the file & save as a string only in db.. if there is any solution please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

An audio file is a binary file. There is no sense in reading it 'line by line'. If you really want to store the audio file in the database, you can read the whole file into a byte array and store it in the database as BINARY/BLOB data.

From a byte[] you can easily create a ByteArrayInputStream (which is a subclass of InputStream, the type of the parameter expected by PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream() and PreparedStatement.setBlob().

See PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream() and PreparedStatement.setBlob():
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: But I don't understand how to implement in my code & and I m so much Confused can u please show me the code